# AWS FTP behavior

Tags: amazon-s3, ftp

I'm having some issue on my AWS S3 bucket and vsftpd.

I've created a vsftpd instance and mount AWS S3 bucket. My issue is that everytime I upload a file and the connection was disrupted, it appends the existing file on the S3 bucket instead of override it when the FTP client retry. What should I set on the S3 bucket policy to have such behavior to override instead of append?

Answer (score 1):

There are no Amazon S3 configuration settings that would impact this behaviour -- it is totally the result of the software you are using.

It's also worth mentioning that FTP is a rather old protocol and these days there are much better alternatives, such as uploads via the browser or Dropbox-like shared folders.

One of the easiest options is to have your users **upload directly to Amazon S3** -- that way, you don't need to run any servers. This could be done by uploading via a browser, or by providing users with some software, such as [Cloudberry Explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx) or the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

I highly encourage you to stop using FTP these days.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 

We're running on a propriety software and it only supports FTP protocol.